# NIC binding order

Tags: powershell

I wrote a command to check NIC binding order. But the problem here is, I am getting all NIC details of the machine, but the binding order listed is not correct.

Can anyone help me to correct this command, so that I can get the NIC details in binding order ?

```
$adapter = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {(Get-NetAdapter).Name }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `InterfaceMetric` is the 'weight' of a specific Interface in `Get-NetIPInterface`, hopefully that's what you're looking for.

```
Get-NetIPInterface | Select Interface*,AddressFamily | Sort InterfaceMetric -Descending
```

Narrowing it down to only 'valid' endpoints (you can exclude IPv6 from this afterwards if needed)

```
Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPInterface | Select Interface*,AddressFamily | ? {$_.InterfaceMetric} | Sort InterfaceMetric -Desc
```

Comment: Result from above command is this
Weight Name
------ ----
    50 isatap.{65DB0E11-CDA7-49EE-AAE8-EA42F72085C1}
    50 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
    50 Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
    50 isatap.{F18C2825-B6E3-4171-AEC0-DA468FEFC18C}
    50 isatap.{0A9626C3-264D-497A-B2BB-7170703413B3}
     5 Local Area Connection* 11
     5 Local Area Connection* 11
     5 storage
     5 vEthernet (10.211.21.0_21)

Comment: But what I am looking for is something like this                                                          Binding Name
------- ----
      1 vEthernet (10.211.21.0_21)
      2 storage
      3 Ethernet 5
      4 Ethernet 4
      5 Ethernet 2
      6 Ethernet 6

Comment: This command seems to be working.But how can I remove disabled/not present NIC from output                                                                            Get-NetAdapter | Select @{n='ifIndex';e={$_.Name}} | sort ifIndex -Descending